# Drupal 7 Views Contextual Filters

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7

I'm trying to create a view with a contextual filter on the title of the node and was wonder if there was a way to pass in a single letter as the argument and have the view return all node that begin with that letter?

Currently I've not found a way to do this, I have to pass in the full title of the node for it to work properly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you looking to create an Alphabet type filter?

Comment: Yep, got it working with some help from #drupal-support IRC gonna put the answer in in a few minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this to work I had to provide a default value: [image: Default Value]

And then I also had set up the Glossary Mode: [image: Glossary Mode]

I had set up the Glossary Mode before but it wasn't working the way I had expected. I guess the default value is required for it to work?

Comment: I used "Display all results for the specified field" instead of the "default value" option. It can be useful in case you don't have content items whose title begins with "A".