# Drupal 7 Views 3 glossary mode: where is it?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have searched all over and I'm having trouble with the Views 3 UI. I can't find where to turn on the glossary mode in the view settings for an attachment. I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I see it in the screen shot for the answer to this question: [Drupal 7 Views Contextual Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232720/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters?s=7411cfbc-4950-4dbc-97eb-0f8d3fc506df#new-answer)

So it must exist?! I'm using Views 7.x-3.0-rc1

Comment: There's a screenshot here that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232720/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters

Answer (score 11):

There are 2 view displays you need to create to make this work.

## Create the Page display

1. First create the page display
2. Add the appropriate fields you wish to display
3. Add a contextual filter argument that you will use for the glossary

> In the settings for the field, make sure to select the 'more' option and set the argument to behave in glossary mode. I believe you also need to set the default value to 'all' or 'a' or any other letter.

## Create the Attachment display

1. Add an attachment display to your view

> If you created all your fields in the page, this version should have all of them.
>
> Override the contextual argument you selected for the page.
>
> Change this to display in summary mode.
>   You will get different options depending on how you want to display your glossary. The Glossary mode should already be enabled.
>
> Assign the attachment to the page in the Attachment settings
>
> Turn off the inheriting of contextual filters (i.e. arguments) within the attachment display.
>
> The best tip I received for learning how to set this up was from [merlinofchaos](https://drupal.org/user/26979) who said to enable the Glossary view in the list of views. He said to clone it and make your changes.
>   This gave me a thorough understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a Contextual Filter setup under the Advanced section of your View.  Once you have one, click on your Contextual filter. In the dialog that comes up, click on `MORE` to expand the items for that section. You should find Glossary mode checkbox there.